# Toast not show if no network connection available

Tags: android

My code does not show toast message if network is unavailable. This is my code below... If no network available toast will not show. What is error in my code? help me please.

```
public class HomeMenu extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homemenu);

        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(HomeMenu.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeMenu.this, getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Util class:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Did you remember to add the `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions?

Comment: Youre context of the TOAST looks kinda strange. have you tried using getApplicationContext() instead? And for the sake of testing add also a fixed string, maybe youre predefined no_internet string is malformed

Comment: yes i give it permission

Comment: have you add permission for internet?

Comment: yes offcourse i give it

Comment: Do you have the `isNetworkAvailable()` method in the same activity? if so, why are you requesting to send an `Activity`?

Comment: no  is available is in utils class see above

Comment: if i disbale network conection from pc it wil not show toast message

Comment: check the ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/18247235/1140237

Answer (score -1):

try this one worked for me ... with req permission android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

```
public class HomeMenu extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homemenu);
    if (!isUserOnline(this)) {
        toast("No Network");
    }

}

public static boolean isUserOnline(Context context) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager nConManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (nConManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo nNetworkinfo = nConManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (nNetworkinfo != null) {
                return nNetworkinfo.isConnected();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}

void toast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: my  network code is in another class utils  not on same class home so how i will pas toast from util class to home class??

Comment: keep isUserOnline method in your util class and access is in you activity like... if (!Utils.isUserOnline(this)) {
        toast("No Network");
    }